# IIS Express with VS2010 SP 1 beta problem

Tags: visual-studio, iis, iis-express, visual-studio-2010

I have installed VS2010 SP1 and IIS Express Beta. Both are installed correctly, but I can't use them because the option does not appear in the context menu as Scott Guthrie describes on his blog here:
http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2011/01/03/vs-2010-sp1-beta-and-iis-developer-express.aspx

What am I doing wrong? What should I do to activate IIS Express?

Comment: Pray tell, who is Scott and what exactly did he say?

Comment: I think he means this post http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2011/01/03/vs-2010-sp1-beta-and-iis-developer-express.aspx

Comment: Scott Guthrie, and he is a Corporate Vice President in the Microsoft Developer Division.yes Artem K he is

Comment: My bad. Scott and I are not on a first name basis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Final version of IIS Express has been released last week. You didn't mention which Beta are you using, but you would be better off with the final version.
- Your Visual Studio 2010 SP1 version (as shown in the Help/About) should be 10.0.31118.1 SP1Rel.
- You could check if IIS Express works on it's own by going to it's installation directory (in Program Files and trying to run iisexpress.exe (should start a sample site WebSite1 on port 8080).

Answer (score 0):

“Converting your existing projects to use IIS Express is really easy.  You can do this by opening up the project properties dialog of an existing project, and then by clicking the “web” tab within it and selecting the “Use IIS Express” checkbox.” — do you have that checkbox?

Comment: Do you really have SP1 installed successfully? What shows up on Help — About menu dialog in VS?

Comment: yes i have installed sp1 successfully and without any error still don't understand what's went wrong with my VS2010.